# Returning path to first and second order "friends"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my application, `Users` are connected by the `Projects` they work on together.  My schema looks like (User)-[:WORKED_ON]->(Project) with multiple users per project and multiple projects per user.
I'd like to be able to show someone their network of not only who they've worked with but also their "friends of friends" that they might want to connect with.

In other words, I want to find Users I'm connected to (either because we're both connected to the same project, or we're both connected to the same person through our projects).

Visually:

- Common project: `(me: User)-[:WORKED_ON]->(:Project)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(collaborator:User)`
- Common Collaborator: `(me: User)-[:WORKED_ON]->(:Project)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(common_collaborator:User)-[:WORKED_ON]->(:Project)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(collaborator:User)`

So end result would be a list something like:

`Jane Doe: You and jane worked on X project
John Doe: You and John have both worked with Jane`

Right now the only way I've found is to do it in several different queries.

1. `MATCH (a:User {user_id: 'theuserid'})-[:WORKED_ON*1..4]-(collaborator:User) RETURN collaborator` which gives me a list of all the collaborators (first and second degree connections).
2. Programmatically loop through each collaborator and query AGAIN for HOW we are connected to them by first querying for common projects, and then for common users.

   `MATCH (user:User {user_id: 'theuserid'}), (other_user: User {user_id: 'otheruserid'}), (user)-[:WORKED_ON]->(common_project:Project)<-[:WORKED_ON]-(other_user) RETURN common_project`


   `MATCH (user:User {user_id: 'theuserid'}), (other_user: User {user_id: 'otheruserid'}), (user)-[:WORKED_ON*2]-(common_collaborator:User)-[:WORKED_ON*2]-(other_user) RETURN common_collaborator`

Surely there's a better way?  Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach already looks pretty good, except that I would use a lower bound of 2 for the variable-length pattern:

```
MATCH (a:User {user_id: 'theuserid'})-[:WORKED_ON*2..4]-(collaborator:User)
RETURN collaborator;
```

Also, you should make sure you have an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/schema/index/) on `:User(user_id)`.

[UPDATE]

Here is a query that will return rows that contain the `user` and data about either a project/collaborator or a common_collaborator/collaborator. This should be what you wanted.

```
MATCH p=(user:User {user_id: 'theuserid'})-[:WORKED_ON*2..4]-(col:User)
RETURN user,
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(p) = 2
    THEN {project: NODES(p)[1], collaborator: col}
    ELSE {common_collaborator: NODES(p)[2], collaborator: col} END AS data;
```

Comment: Thanks @cybersam.  I guess my concern is with the sheer number of queries.  I'm doing one query to get a list of users, and then 2 more queries _per user_ to find out how they wound up being in the result set of the first query.

Comment: Incredible! Will try it out when I get home.  Thanks for your help.